# Can I use a string to refer to a TableName when call a QueryableExtensions method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, extension-methods

I have several tables in a DB file, and want to use QueryableExtensions method to do some query and insert, but I want to use string to refer to a tablename, is it possible or I should user LINQ statements in this case?
Here are the codes,

```
    public string Find(string TableName, string UserCol, string UserName, string FindCol)
    {
        var res = spiritDB.accounts.Where(entry => entry.username == UserName).Select(entry => entry.password);
        //some more codes ...
        //return something;
    }
```

I'm wondering if I can user TableName got from the parameters to refer to spiritDB.accounts when "accounts" is the actual table name, something like spiritDB[TableName], and user FindCol instead of entry.password where the "password" is the column (field) name.
Or I can only use LINQ expressions for this purpose?

I'm pretty new to these extension methods. Thanks very much.

Comment: OK I just realized I was facing the same issue when I attempted to use LINQ expressions, it's not like SQL statements with which one can compose a query expression with strings completely...

Comment: What should I do during design process when I don't know which table will be searched in when the function is called at run time...

Comment: What type would you expect `res` to be given that you want to refer to different tables? You have a bigger issue than picking a table by name (that's easy, just build a `Dictionary<string,T>` but what would `T` be...?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, now the code is "spiritDB.accounts", here "accounts" is the table name. I would like to make it something like "spiritDB.stringvariant", and the string variant can be set at run time, how should I use Dictionary to do that? Would you please give me an example? thanks.

Comment: And “spiritDB” is Data.Entity.DbSet.

Comment: And the db model defined each table as a class type, I can pass a type, e.g. accounts, hoping the DbSet can refer to a table using the type.

Comment: So far I've got a few clues for the table name reference, but it will take a lot of efforts to do the same for the fields, it's not quite efficient and cost effective for the entire project. So I'll work around in another way, but thank you all for the help!